# Access object methods from getattr()

Tags: python, class, getattr

I need to create a script that allows you to access object atributes dynamically from `getattr()` built-in function, but I'm having lots of troubles when trying to access the object methods, here is an example:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 12
        self.name = 'Bobby'
    
    def eat(self):
        print("I'm eating!")
```

If I then initialize the object and try to access their attributes:

```
mydog = Dog()

res = getattr(mydog, 'age')
print(res)
#--> return: 12
```

But if I try to access the `eat` method:

```
mydog = Dog()

res = getattr(mydog, 'eat()')
print(res)
#--> return: AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'eat()'
```

I have already tried to write the method name without quotation marks, and the best solution that I found is to write the method without the parentheses and then access the function from `res`:

```
mydog = Dog()

res = getattr(mydog, 'eat')
res()
#--> return: I'm eating!
```

I could code a conditional that detects if `res` contains a variable or a function and call it in case it's a method, but is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Because `'eat()'` isn't an attribute. `'eat'` is. What exactly are you even asking?

Comment: The attribute is called `eat` and it is a "bound method".  If instead, you had `def eat(item): print("I am eating " + item)` then you could call `res('bone')` just like any other function.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but using the `@property` decorator will make it so that you can "retrieve" the results of `eat()` when you fetch the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `@property` decorator on the method `eat` it will make it so that we can retrieve it without problems with `getattr`:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 12
        self.name = 'Bobby'

    @property
    def eat(self):
        return "I'm eating!"

mydog = Dog()
res1 = getattr(mydog, 'age')
res2 = getattr(mydog, 'name')
res3 = getattr(mydog, 'eat')
print(res1) #Output: 12
print(res2) #Output: Bobby
print(res3) #Output: I'm eating!
```

If we don't make `eat` into a property, then calling `getattr(mydog, "eat")` will return a reference to the method without calling it. However, when you set `@property` in a method, that will create a `getter` of `eat` that will be called when you try to call that attribute.

If we then want to extend the above, so that we can change the value of `eat` then we can also create a `setter` of eat:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self._eat = "I'm eating!"

    @property
    def eat(self):
        return self._eat
    
    @eat.setter
    def eat(self, eat_string):
        self._eat = eat_string

mydog = Dog()
print(mydog.eat) #Output: I'm eating!
mydog.eat = "Stop bothering me!"
print(mydog.eat) #Output: Stop bothering me!
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a small one line condition that will detect it for you isn't bad and it's pretty short using `callable`:

```
attr = getattr(mydog, attr_name)
res = attr() if callable(attr) else attr
```

on Python3.8, you can even one line it:

```
res = attr() if callable(attr := getattr(mydog, attr_name)) else attr
```